# Does Substrate support custom node specific environment vars or flags

Tags: rpc, substrate-node, custom-types

I have a pallet that should have access to a `secp256k1::Keypair` for signing messages. And I want to be able to start the node with either the secret_key string or a path to a key-file. Then have the pallet in question have access to the secret key to construct signing contexts

The limitation of the `keystore` as I understand it is that you can't access the secret key at all. Is there someway of achieving this? Or is using `localstorageSet` the only method of passing node-specific custom/arbitrary information to the runtime